# How convert "string with array format" to array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have this string

```
$string = '["a","b","c"],["a","b","c"],["a","b","c"],["a","b","c"]'
```

i need to convert that string in array like:

```
array(["a","b","c"],["a","b","c"],["a","b","c"],["a","b","c"])
```

Thankyou :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wrap the `$string` in `'[]'`, then you can decode it as JSON.

```
$data = json_decode('[' . $string . ']');
```